# Inno Setup: How to watch variables values or write to debug output?

Tags: debugging, inno-setup, pascalscript

How can I watch values of variables while debugging in Inno Setup? How can I print something to debug output?

Thanks

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There's currently no debug watch window, but you can simply hover the variable you want to inspect, when the debugger is stopped on a breakpoint. To print something to a debug output, use the [`Log`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_log.htm) procedure:

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  Value: Integer;
begin
  Value := 123;
  Log('The Value is: ' + IntToStr(Value));
end;
```

Here is the result of the hovered `Value` variable from the previous script sample:

[image]

And the result of the debug output window after when you step over the `Log` statement:

[image]

Comment: That's helpful, thanks. Wish I could look at properties and values of COM objects. It's worth noting that this hover-to-show approach works in the Inno Setup Compiler, but not in Inno Script Studio or Inno IDE.