# Inno Setup: Exec can't read string?

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascal

I'm trying to put together a simple Inno Setup installer which looks for the previous version and removes it before proceeding. Everything is working fine until I get the following code:

```
  if Exec(UninstallString, '/SILENT', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
  begin
    MsgBox('Previous version found and uninstalled successfully.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end
  else
  begin
    MsgBox('Please uninstall the previous version of this mod before continuing.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    Result := FALSE;
  end;
```

It's a very simple bit of code, but it ALWAYS fails. I've checked the contents of `UninstallString` and they're correct (`C:\Windows\unins000.exe`) but the [Exec](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_exec.htm) fails with the error: **"The directory name is invalid."**

It appears that it can't read the contents of "UninstallString" correctly, because if I enter them manually (e.g. `Exec('C:\Windows\unins000.exe, ...`) it works fine.

How can I make `Exec` process the string "UninstallString" as intended?

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I got the following error: "The directory name is invalid."

Comment: Yes, I'm definitely looking up the previous AppId. Secondly, as stated in the question, I've checked the contents of the string and they're as expected :-/

Comment: That's impossible. There's generally no difference between the string constant and a `string` type variable with the same value as the constant. The problem must be somewhere else. Don't you use `AnsiString` type e.g. for the `UninstallString` variable, don't you ?

Comment: I use: `UninstallString: string;` is that wrong? And, I promise you, the contents are there. I just checked again. It's boggling my mind.

Comment: No, that's correct. Then there is (from inside the `Exec` function point of view) absolutely no difference between that constant and the variable having the same value as the constant. I'm starting to think about some non-printable char in that registry value... How did you check the `UninstallString` value ?

Comment: I placed it in a MsgBox... This is such a weird thing. Everything else is working fine! Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Try to set a breakpoint to line with `Exec` call and [`watch or log the value`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14674126/960757) of the `UninstallString` variable. There should be visible also non-printable chars (as some extraordinary chars). Although it's weird how would non-printable chars appear in registry and be read by Windows API registry functions, it's the only thing that comes to my mind to explain the difference between string constant and a `string` variable with the same value printed by `MsgBox`.

Comment: I wonder if it's not `Exec` who failed but your `unins000.exe` failed with "The directory name is invalid.". It is strange that it does run when given the string directly. BTW Why would your `unins000.exe` be in the Windows directory instead of a program directory (unless you installed your program in `C:\Windows`)? (and there should also be a `unins000.dat`.)

Comment: Yeah, this is why I'm trying to clean things up a bit. Lol! It's a patch installer, so there's no main executable folder, but I think it would be better if I made one, instead of the installer automatically using `{win}` :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you already did the `MsgBox` to determine the **exact** string in the registry for the `UninstallString` but in the registry the normal string is `"C:\Windows\unins000.exe"`.

Note the **extra** `"` around the command.

When using `Exec` with the `"` around the command you get a ResultCode 267 which is an `invalid directory` error. So you need to strip them before the `Exec`.

When you entered the `C:\Windows\unins000.exe` manually in `Exec` you conveniently forgot them ;)

Comment: The `MsgBox` way for printing out string values is not the best way because you lose non-printable chars. And those might be serious problem for this case (but it seems they are not).

Comment: Yeah, but `"` is a printable character and I think the command is wrapped around `"` (which `Exec` can't handle).

Comment: No, I meant that the file name we are talking about might contain non-printable chars, like e.g. #8, #9 and whatever. And those you won't see through `MsgBox` and they might be problem for `Exec`. `MsgBox` is not the right way to see the real string value. Howgh! :-)

Comment: @Rik Well done for spotting this! I outputted the value to Log, as TLama suggested, and it was indeed "C:\Windows\unins000.exe"!