# Stripping quotation marks in Pascal/Inno Setup

Tags: string, inno-setup, pascal

I have a string, `"c:\windows\unins000.exe"`, that I need to turn into, `c:\windows\unins000.exe`. It would be easy enough to do in another language, but I need to do it in Inno Setup/Pascal.

The problem I'm having is that I get an "invalid directory" error when I run

```
Exec(UninstallString, '/SILENT', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)
```

with the above string, and it appears that it's [the quotation marks that are causing the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213376/inno-setup-exec-cant-read-string).

I can't even find an example of ANY string functions in Pascal or Inno Setup! :-/

Comment: Use [`RemoveQuotes`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_removequotes.htm) function.

Comment: Note that you don't actually need to remove the quotes from that string.  Use `Exec('', UninstallString + ' /SILENT', ...)` instead.  (Or just fetch the `QuietUninstallString`, which already has `/SILENT` in it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha! I found it hidden away in the manual. Google wasn't being too helpful today.

You can use [RemoveQuotes](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_removequotes.htm)!

Simple.

Comment: It's not hidden at all. Whenever you'll need to find a certain function, go to [`Support Functions Reference`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptfunctions.htm), look for a category you need (in this case *String functions*) and there you can quickly find a function with the *"Quotes"* keyword directly in its name. Don't use Google for that. That help site is not well indexed there, but it doesn't even need to be, if you know it. A similar help with the same content you have shipped with Inno Setup itself, so you don't even go online for those information.

Comment: @TLama Yes, I know that *now*! :-P